# Publishing Springboot webapp on AWS 404 index error

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, maven

I'm trying to learn Java and I've done a Springboot application using Eclipse and Maven. I started downloading the base from https://start.spring.io/ and then I created my first controller and jsp index page. But when I try to package it in war and publish it on AWS elasticbeanstalk I had this error:

Sat Oct 05 09:42:45 UTC 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp

I state that:
- When I run the web app on my computer it works perfectly!
- I've already set on AWS (in the custom variables) to change the port on 5000

This is the project structure

portfolio

```
- src
  - main
    - java
    - resources (where i have static and application.properties
    - webapp
      - WEB-INF
        - jsp
          - index.jsp
pom.xml
```

This is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    war
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.1.9.RELEASE
         
    
    com.sofidis
    portfolio
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    portfolio
    Portfolio project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.26</version>
        <!-- aggiunto per creare il war -->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<!-- plugin repository aggiunto per compilare il war -->
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- precedente <plugin> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            </plugin> -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This is the application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

This is my the main controller PortfolioApplication.java

```
package com.sofidis.portfolio;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;



@SpringBootApplication
public class PortfolioApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PortfolioApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(PortfolioApplication.class);
    }

}
```

This is my HomeController

```
import com.sofidis.portfolio.model.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController 
{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index( HttpSession session) 
    {

        PageMeta ptitle = new PageMeta();
        String titlepagina= ptitle.getPtitle("index");      
        session.setAttribute("pagetitle", titlepagina);

        PageMeta pdesc = new PageMeta();
        String descpagina= pdesc.getPdescription("index");      
        session.setAttribute("pagedescription", descpagina);

        return "index"; 

    }


}
```

And this is the index.jps

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>${pagetitle}</title>
<meta name="description" content="${pagedescription}">
<jsp:include page="./includes/common_head.jsp" />
</head>
<body>
 <p>Hello World</p>                             

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for help!! I'm desperate :((

Comment: Check your project jar/war/ear file which you are deploying in AWS to see if this path exist in build.  /WEB-INF/jsp/

Comment: How can I check it? In the "target" folder I have the portfolio-0.0.01-SNAPSHOT.war and I have a sub-folder that has the same name. Inside this sub-folder I have the jsp folder, the META-INF folder and the WEB-inf folder at the same level.

Answer (score 0):

Under WEB-INF you should only place classes, libraries, web.xml. The JSPs should be placed on the same level as WEB-INF, not under WEB-INF. In your case it should be as follows:

```
webapp
  WEB-INF
    ...
  jsp
    index.jsp
```

Afterwards there can also other problems. But first change the structure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to change the structure and place it at the same level, but I still have the error :(